# HighCharts using Themeroller

Tags: jquery-ui, highcharts

Has anyone been able to successfully get HighCharts to use ThemeRoller themes in order to change its look and feel? If not do you know of any links, blogs, forums, etc where someone has tried and got it to partially work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I didn't find any way to do what you ask. Will be better if all styling element are defined in the site css and not in a styling specific js function (!!). I add a question to the highchart forum, if isn't spam, we can vote it:
http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/2406595-jquery-ui

Comment: Do you know how I would go about doing this myself. I don't have time to wait.

Comment: I think you can try to override the SVG shapes and use your jQuery UI CSS http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-and-css.html; but if the highcharts change the render method can be a problem. You can try to have a look.